# No option to install Lubuntu from USB on a Ubuntu system

Tags: boot, 14.04, usb, lubuntu

I have a netbook (Asus eee PC 1001P) running Ubuntu 13.10. I want to install Lubuntu 14.04 on it. I downloaded the Lubuntu ISO and used Unetbootin (on my newer laptop, running Ubuntu 14.04) to create a bootable USB with the iso file. But when I start the netbook with the USB stick plugged in, it just boots straight into Ubuntu 13.10. Holding down shift shows the GRUB menu, but the USB system is not listed there.

I also tried creating the USB with the same ISO file and usb-creator-gtk, with the same result (the USB seems invisible to the netbook during boot). The USB mounts fine on the netbook once Ubuntu is already loaded. Any ideas?

Comment: The option to boot from the USB would be a BIOS option - you will need to access the computers BIOS and indicate that you want to boot from tat rather than from the HDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have a ASUS EeePC 1000 and I have Lubuntu 14.04 installed.  For some reason the computer recognizes the flash drive as another hard drive.  When you start the computer, enter the BIOS.  Navigate to boot and then down to the hard drive.  You will notice that there is a plus sign there.  Click on the hard drive and you will see your flash drive.  Move it to the top, save your changes (F10 I believe), and continue with the boot.  Hopefully that will solve your problem.

Comment: «For some reason the computer recognizes the flash drive as another hard drive» This is what most laptops do. It is a driver, after all. :)

Comment: Thanks Rex. I didn't quite understand your comment until after messing about in the BIOS menu a bit. There is one item to change the boot order of USB/HDD and there is another to choose among HDDs (which in this case includes the bootable USB stick). Changing both those options eventually did the trick.