# Asus Eee won't boot

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, asus, eeepc

I have a Asus Eee PC running Ubuntu but I wanted to change to Lubuntu, so I created a bootable USB pen drive with Lubuntu (that works fine, I tryed it no my desktop).

I was able to boot on my Eee PC and got to the part to manage the partitions. I deleted all partitions because i wanted to have only Lubuntu running but then accidently I unplugged my computer and now I can't boot from the usb pen.
It just boots into Ubuntu log in page and after I login nothing happens. I've tryed reinstalling ubuntu-desktop but it wont install.

I know everything is right with my usb pen and bootable device priority on BIOS.

What can I do to install Lubuntu.

Comment: I would bet on the USB pen being corrupted during the unplug. Try to format and recreate it....

Answer (score 0):

Before you format and recreate your bootable flash drive.  Check the BIOS under Boot->Hard Drive.  Your flash drive may be found there.  If it is move it to the top of the list, save the changes, exit and continue with the boot.  However, Rmano has a good point in that flash drives sometimes become unusable when you do not unmount them properly.
See my comments on [No option to install Lubuntu from USB on a Ubuntu system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521966/no-option-to-install-lubuntu-from-usb-on-a-ubuntu-system)